# select row where the slot is the biggest

Tags: php, mysql, join

i need to select one row where slot_left is the biggest. i tried

```
for ( $i=1;$i<3;$i++) {
    $sql5 = "SELECT * from user u where (
        select max(slot_left) from company c,user u 
        where c.id=u.company_id and c.id='$name'
    )";
    $result5 = mysqli_query($link, $sql5) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) {  
        // echo the id which the slot_left is the biggest      
        echo $i['slot_left'];
    }
}
```

but still cannot. please help!

Comment: please add format to your code

Comment: echo $i['slot_left'];
... can't be right, probably should be $row['slot_left']

Comment: Your inner query does not have a closing paren ?

Comment: looks like shotgun debugging for me... "Does not work -> post it on stackoverflow..."...

Comment: Where does $name come from? c.id would suggest an integer value but $name suggests a string.

Answer (score 0):

1. SQL can be. You select all rows from DB.

   $sql5 = "select max(slot_left) AS slot_left from company c,user u where c.id=u.company_id and c.id='$name' GROUP by u.company_id";
2. $name variable used in query not set
3. Variable $i is not array. Array is $row

   echo $row['slot_left'];

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `GROUP BY` in your query.
And query execution in Loop is not recommended, it will decrees performance.

Try this.

```
$sql5 = "select c.id, max(slot_left) from company c,user u 
        where c.id=u.company_id and c.id='$id' GROUP by c.id";

    $result5 = mysqli_query($link, $sql5) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) {  
        echo $row['slot_left'];
    }
```